# How do you upload Angular Fullstack app to prexisting Heroku app?

Tags: git, heroku, angular-fullstack

When I do:

```
grunt buildcontrol:heroku
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: remote: !  No such app as <wrongapp>
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/<wrongapp>/' not found
 Use --force to continue.
```

When I try:

```
remote -v
```

I get:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:<rightapp> (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:<rightapp> (push)
origin  https://github.com/anApp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/anApp.git (push)
```

Everything looks in order given the git remote -v.

So then I try:

```
git push -f heroku
```

and I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now I'm not sure how that can be since I've done:

```
heroku login
```

Moreover I'm not sure if that message is even relevant as I should be able to use grunt buildcontrol:heroku.

Comment: Same error myself. You ever fix it? I can't find where the old name is loaded o.O

Comment: @ Anthony Mayfield - I'm not sure what you mean by old name.  Here are a few things I suggest doing:

1) Make sure your package.json reflects all of the necessary dependencies in your node_modules directory.

2) Check the dist/git/config and make sure the correct heroku app is in that directory.

3) root/dist/FETCH_HEAD and root/dist/config: make sure to update these and match with prexisting versions.